# express session key property

Tags: session, express

i try to build an app with authentication system in express. for keeping user on session, i use express session middleware. when i configure session, i wonna know, if the session key property have to assign or not. This sample is from some book.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.sessionSecret = 'SocialNet secret key';
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.limit('1mb'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: app.sessionSecret,
    key: 'express.sid',
    store: app.sessionStore
  }));
  mongoose.connect(dbPath, function onMongooseError(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

And whats gonna happen, when i don't assign a value to session key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`express.session` uses `connect.session` underneath; if you look at [its documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html), it will use `connect.sid` as a default key in case you don't provide one yourself:

> Options:
>
> - `key` **cookie name defaulting to `connect.sid`**
> - ...

Comment: link not work, can u explain it how can connect cookie to express-session

Answer (score 0):

@robertklep's answer is out of date:

A session key is now mandatory. You must provided it and the defense of the secrets contained within are dependent on selecting a good key. My recommendation is selecting a key with sufficient entropy (128 bits) and periodically changing it.

see: https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/test/session.js#L38

Comment: perhaps you are confusing key with secret?

Comment: @jpierson at the time of this writing i believe it was called "key" (over a year ago) you can see the line of code doesnt match anymore either.